# Issue to cast proxy object

Tags: java, hana, cmis

I try to integrate CMIS using HANA Cloud Document service with Maven and Spring.

When I try to use that code without Maven/Spring context, it works fine.
(To better understand, please take a look here: http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/cloud-platform/blog/2013/04/13/document-management-using-hana-cloud-document-service-on-android)

```
        Session openCmisSession = null;
        EcmService ecmSvc = null;
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        String lookupName = "java:comp/env/" + "EcmService";
        try
        {   
          Object obj = ctx.lookup(lookupName);
          ecmSvc = (EcmService) obj; 
        }       
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Using Spring, the exception occurs when it tries to cast proxy object.

```
ecmSvc = (EcmService) obj; //Here, the EcmService is a interface
```

The exception is below. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146 cannot be cast to com.sap.ecm.api.EcmService
>
> ```
> at com.msg.reinsurance.application.account.service.FindAccountFacadeImp.findContract(FindAccountFacadeImp.java:93)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
> at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:189)
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99)
> at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
> at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
> at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:298)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:222)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:273)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
> at com.sap.core.jpaas.security.auth.service.lib.AbstractAuthenticator.invoke(AbstractAuthenticator.java:168)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
> at com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invokeNextValve(TenantValidationValve.java:167)
> at com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invoke(TenantValidationValve.java:91)
> at com.sap.js.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:34)
> at com.sap.core.js.monitoring.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:27)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a best bet I'd think that you are packing the resp. client libraries into your application so they clash with the ones already provided by the platform (due to different classloaders).
Double-check this.
Additionally should the problem not be caused by my assumption, you can check for another workaround here: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3803685